# How to increase the value in a excel sheet by some percentage

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with multiple sheets with some numerical values. I want to increase these values by some percentage, lets say 10%. How can I achieve using a vb script.

Comment: @pnuts:  An excellent alternative!

Answer (score 1):

Just for diversity:

```
Sub Multiply()
MyMultiplier = 5      'Set your Multiply value here
For i = 1 To 10       'Set your last cell here
    For j = 1 To 10   'Set your last column here
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)) Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j).Value * MyMultiplier
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Might also try to check if cell contains anithing with

```
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j) <> "" Then
```

The code is Tested and it's Working, but it's **NOT RECOMENDED** :) Just stick to `Excel Formulas` and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
Sub Increment()
    Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value = Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value * 1.1
    Sheets(2).Range("B9").Value = Sheets(2).Range("B9").Value * 1.1
End Sub
```

for one cell in each of two sheets.